# Display images on a plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I've got a matrix:

```
0 [2 3 1 4 1 3 1 2]
1 [1 0 0 2 1 2 1 0]
2 [2 0 2 1 1 0 2 0]
3 [1 0 0 0 2 0 0 2]
4 [2 0 1 0 1 3 0 0]
5 [1 0 0 2 0 1 0 4]
6 [3 2 0 0 1 2 2 0]
7 [4 1 2 0 2 3 1 2]
```

Where each cell indicates a number of JPG images that corresponds to it.
Do you know if there is a simple way, for instance with `matplotlib`, to plot on plane the images corresponding to each cell of the matrix on a grid ? That is to have a grid, divided into cells, cells being filled with the associated images. 
Here for instance we would have 2 images on the top left cell etc...

I couldn't find a way to plot images with `matplotlib` as you would in 2D graphical frameworks (such as `pygame` or `SDL`) where you have an abstract plane on which you can place objects as images at given coordinates.

The only reason why I would like to do it with `matplotlib` is to fit a `jupyter`, `numpy`, `matplotlib` framework of mine.

Thank you very much for your attention

**EDIT:** This matplotlib feature should do the trick:
https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#a-complex-nested-gridspec-using-subplotspec

Comment: I don't quite understand the concept. Are the cells squared? How would you plot 3 images in the square cell? Will they be squeezed?

Comment: Yes, we can assume the cells are squared, the images can of course be resized. I wonder if there a simple and clever way to dispatch `n` images on a square. Of course a subgrid sized at the highest `n` on the matrix would fit, but it's not very satisfactory.

Comment: Rather the Least common multiple of the numbers in the matrix. In any case, there is no prebuilt function to that kind of thing in matplotlib.

Comment: Why the lcm ? If for instance I have only a cell with 3 images and a cell with 5, I would divide each cells in `int(sqrt(5))+1 = 3` sized squares and everybody fits, no ? 
Ok, do you think of a simple framework for making such visualizations? Thank you again

Comment: In fact I might have found what I need within matplotlib!! 
https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#a-complex-nested-gridspec-using-subplotspec

Comment: I was actually thinking about exactly that gridspec. There for a 3 picture cell and a 5 picture cell you would need a grid of lcm(3,5)=15 columns. The 3 pictures from the first cell need to span 5 columns each, while the pictures of the second cell would need to span 3 columns each.

Comment: Ah yes ok, sure! Thank you very much for your help :)